# How does Django knows which template to render when?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am on 4th chapter the book Django 3 by example and I noticed one thing that we are only creating views from Django's authentication framework but we are not telling those views which template to render when.
For example, how does my application would know that it needs to only render the logged_out.html template when we try to access the logout view? If I try to change the name of the file from logged_out.html to loggedout.html then it takes me to the Django's admin logout page.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `Django` built-in views for authentication like login and logout etc.

You can read more about these views [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

According to `Django` docs login view will look for **registration/login.html** template if you don't specify the template name.

For logout view `Django` by default  look for **registration/logged_out.html**. You can also specify your own template by overriding the default one.

For overriding specify the name of your template in `.as_view()` method. Like this

```
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name="yourLoginTemplate.html"), name="view_name"),  
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name="yourLogoutTemplate.html"), name="view_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

In django views, for each view we write at the end

`return render(request, 'your template location')`

That is how django knows which template to render for which view.

Comment: `render()` take **template name** instead of template location. Template location is specified in `settings.py`

Comment: No render takes the template location

Comment: You can read [render docs] clarification.  
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)